# E-Mail queue to be able to clear sent mail

Tags: email, queue

Have you ever had sent an e-mail (e.g. to a customer) where you noticed an important error one second after you have sent it (though proof-read before)? The browser-based home banking system of my bank has some kind of bank transfer queue. It allows to edit or delete bank scheduled transfers for an half hour, even after logging out and logging in again.

Does anybody knows a tool between the e-mail client and e-mail server which delays the e-mails for a short period of time, e.g. 15min, and allows to easily clear messages out of the queue to prevent final sending?

**Update:**

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird on Windows and connect to an SSL/TLS authenticated postfix server on Linux.

Comment: You would need to include more information on what email server you are using and the client you use. Include OS's for each. If it is a public email server, then I doubt there is anything, if it is an email server you manage, then I suppose there would be a solution.

Comment: I've did not add this information initially, because I thought about a tool which could be a "man in the middle" between any common e-mail client and any common e-mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla Thunderbird has a plugin "Send Later" with the desired feature.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know from your question what email client you are using, but if you happen to be using Outlook, you can create a rule to delay sending emails for X number of minutes.  Create a blank rule, and select Check messages after sending.  On the next screen, select any filters you want.  And on the next screen select defer delivery by a number of minutes and edit the number of minutes.

This will hold email messages in your Outbox for X number of minutes before sending them on to the email server.  Of course, if you close Outlook before it gets sent, the message never gets sent until the next time you open Outlook.